# FAILURE: No target filename specified

Tags: gdal, clip, gdalwarp

Each time I run

`gdalwarp -te 212051.9319179999874905 214051.9319179999874905 183962.2946890000021085 Quada.tif Clipped.tif`

I get the following error:

FAILURE: No target filename specified.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 4):

`-te` accepts 4 arguments (`-te xmin ymin xmax ymax`), but you added 3 coordinates only. `Quada.tif` is then recognized as `ymax` and `Clipped.tif` as input file.